# Jquery .animate() ignoring animation duration

Tags: jquery

The fade_time variable is set to 3000, but the animation is much quicker than this. I have  also tried passing in 3000 instead of sing the variable, but this hasn't helped. Here is my code, any ideas most welcome.

```
$images.filter(':eq(' + current_pic_idx + ')').css({
    zIndex: 50
});
$images.filter(':eq(' + nextPic + ')').css({
    zIndex: 100,
    opacity: 0
}).animate({
    opacity: 100
}, {
    duration: fade_time,
    complete: function () {
        $images.filter(':eq(' + current_pic_idx + ')').css({
            zIndex: 0
        });

        current_pic_idx = current_pic_idx + 1;
        if (current_pic_idx == $images.size()) {
            current_pic_idx = 0;
        }

        window.setTimeout(showNextImage, timer_delay);
    }
});
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle with minimal example. There is too much code irrelevant to the question here.

Comment: My only logical conclusion is that the problem is exactly in `fade_time` which in probably not a number but a string, not being recognized as a valid value by jQuery, and set to the default duration (400);

Comment: does it enter the `complete` function?

Comment: your code doesn't set `fade_time` to any value so jQuery will use the default (400 ms, I think)

Comment: @StephenThomas _The fade_time variable is set to 3000,_ He says that in the first line of the question .

Comment: I'm having this exact issue .. did anyone resolve it but not post a solution or that they worked around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following syntax:

```
.animate({
    opacity: 100
}, fade_time, function () {
        $images.filter(':eq(' + current_pic_idx + ')').css({
            zIndex: 0
        });

        current_pic_idx = current_pic_idx + 1;
        if (current_pic_idx == $images.size()) {
            current_pic_idx = 0;
        }
     window.setTimeout(showNextImage, timer_delay);
    });
```